Unable To Serve Webp Images Through htaccess
I'm having problem to serve webp format images through htaccess. I have followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-serve-webp-images-to-speed-up-your-website and https://gist.github.com/seeekr/2415528 links code. before helping me, I want to clarify something.
First, images are in many subfolders. for example: public_html/wp-content/uploads/2023/10, 2024/02, 2024/05 like that.
Second, in every folder i have image.jpg format and image.jpg.webp format. server is not picking the image.jpg.webp. I want to use that format.
third, my .htaccess is in the public_html folder.
Here are the codes I tried:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Check if browser supports WebP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp

# Check if WebP version of the image exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f

# Serve the WebP version if available
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=Cache-Control:vary=webp]

# Add the Vary header to inform browsers and proxies about WebP support
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp)$">
    Header append Vary Accept
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp

then I have used:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %1\.webp -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !type=original
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]

then:
# Check if the requested file is a supported image format
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ [NC]

# Check if a corresponding WebP version exists in the same directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.webp -f

# Serve the .webp version instead
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ $1.$2.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1,L]

and then:
# Only target images within the wp-content/uploads folder (and its subfolders)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/ [NC]

# Check if a WebP version of the file exists (recursively in subfolders)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.webp -f

# Serve the .webp version if it exists
RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ $1.$2.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1,L]

also used this one:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)\.(jpe?g|png)$ /$1.$2.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=EXISTING:1,E=ADDVARY:1,L]

and finally I have tried this one too:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/uploads/2023/10/(.+)(?:\.jpe?g|\.png)$    
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/uploads/2023/10/%1.webp -f
RewriteRule ^/uploads/2023/10/%1.webp [L,T=image/webp,E=accept:1]

none of them picks image.jpg.webp format, always chooses image.jpg format. What can I do?

May I ask how you generate the webp format of images, by which plugin? Does that plugin have any rewrite rules for such cases?
If you have server access, you can also enable the rewrite log to track which rules have been processed.

"none of them picks image.jpg.webp format, always chooses image.jpg format." - and how exactly did you determine that was the case? These are not redirects, but only internal rewrites - so you won't see any URLs changing on the client side. The indicator you should be looking for as to whether this has worked or not, is the Content-Type header in the response.
